# get dns record through specific nameserver

Tags: php, dns

is it possible to get a dns record - dns_get_record() - through a specific nameserver in my php script?

The build in function dns_get_record() only uses the dns servers from the local system.

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: Not unless you edit your server's resolver, which you probably don't want to do. I'd recommend something like [React DNS](https://reactphp.org/dns/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, dns_get_record() doesn't let you specify the nameserver.

You could use system() and call a system utility that does, such as “host” or “dig”.

Comment: Never shell out when you have everything in your programming language to do things you need. Starting a shell, besides not even being possible in all setup, bring you only downside: performance issues, security vulnerabilities, difficulties in trying to parse an output that was never expected to be parsed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found **Net_DNS2** / **Net_DNS** - it works fine